# How should I store The Raveonettes' Pe'ahi limited edition vinyl with gel-filled sleeve?

Tags: vinyl

The limited edition of The Raveonettes 2014's Pe'ahi album comes with a gel-filled sleeve.
Stored in vertical position, all the gel that fills the sleeve goes down, with the risk of pressing too much the vinyl on the bottom side, damaging it.
Stored in horizontal position, I'm also afraid that the weight of the gel and the non-homogeneous distribution can cause vinyl warping.

Should I just change the sleeve with a *normal* one? Or I have a safe way to store this *special* package?

You can find info & pictures of the vinyl I'm talking about [here](https://www.discogs.com/Raveonettes-Peahi/release/6000336) and [here](http://www.popsike.com/The-Raveonettes-Peahi-Vinyl-Lp-Ltd-Ed-Clear-Gel-Filled-Sleeve/291329899707.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch out the sleeve.  There's really no advantage to keeping it in the original sleeve unless you're primarily interested in displaying it, not playing it.